# How often should multiplayer games communicate with the server?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, server

I once heard that Runescape "ticks" every 0.3s, and that seemed like a very long period of time, although Runescape is kind of a slow game.

I'm building a more dynamic top-down shooter game, and I'm wandering, how often should I communicate with the server? ASAP, or every 0.1s? How do shooter games usually do it?

Both the server and the client are written in Javascript, node.js and socket.io are being used.

Comment: how much responsibility is given to what parties: do clients update to send new data to server, so server can propagate to other clients? does client send a command request to the server, and wait for propagation from server? does the client send a command request, and still attempt to update while awaiting for propagation from server? some of these demand higher frequency of update then others, and effect what happens when connection is lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

30 times per second is a common packet rate, but that's really a very very small part of te equation.

Check out [Networking for Game Programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/) for a great intro article to game networking for latency sensitive designs like shooters.

Comment: Updated with link, let me know if it's wrong.